# does existsByid Query includes limit 1?

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql

i tried use existsByid

```
@GetMapping("/{memberId}")
    public boolean getMember(@PathVariable("memberId") long memberId) {
        return memberRepository.existsById(memberId);
    }
```

and jpa send query like this

```
    select
        m1_0.member_id 
    from
        member m1_0 
    where
        m1_0.member_id=?
```

it doesn't show limit 1
so I declared the method using a custom JPQL Query with @Query like this and sent the Query

```
    @Query()
    boolean existsByMemberId(long memberId);


    @GetMapping("/{memberId}")
    public boolean getMember(@PathVariable("memberId") long memberId) {
        return memberRepository.existsById(memberId);
    }
```

and then query included limit 1

```
 select
        m1_0.member_id 
    from
        member m1_0 
    where
        m1_0.member_id=? 
    limit
        ?
```

so I just wonderd existsById include limit 1 but doesn't show in the query
or doesn't include limit 1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a side-effect of overriding/declaring CRUD repository methods.

Either way, `limit 1` is pointless for simple `existsBy...` methods.

These methods are transformed to SQL `select count()...` queries, which without `group by` always return 1 and only 1 row.